# How can i get rid of the red background in the laravel errors' console output

Tags: php, laravel, intellij-idea

i just set  up intellij idea to work with laravel but the console output is not clear see image to know more about what am saying

[Console output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WFTEA.png)

Comment: changed console ANSI colors

Comment: It say's solve, what's the solution?

Comment: Okay, you place question fast and you answer the question fast.

Comment: well, i needed to keep digging while waiting for answers, couldn't just sit back and relax. it was unfortunate that i got to the answer first

Comment: Is this, or is this not, solved?

Comment: It's better to answer the question, in `answer section`, with the detailed explanation. So, others can know how to solve the same problem. That's how stackoverflow works. Then, you don't need to add `solved` to the title.

Comment: Please do not post images of code or logs, copy your code or logs into the question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

changed console ANSI colors. from setting-> console colors i changed the ANSI color for grey to white and made the red darker

[new console output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qVUr2.png)

[Settings Screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u2ckm.png)